# how do i resolve this exception "Syntext error into INSERT INTO statement".p

Tags: c#, sql, sql-insert

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ACCOUNT.oo.Open();
    string QRY = "insert into size(SIZENO,SIZE,COVERAGE,WEIGHT) 
        values('" + size_id.Text + "','" +txt_size.Text + "','" +txt_coverage.Text  
        + "','" +txt_weight.Text + "')";
    OleDbCommand ODB = new OleDbCommand(QRY,ACCOUNT.oo);
    ODB.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted Sucessfully..");
    ACCOUNT.oo.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you set a break point, what is the actual value of `QRY`? Also look into parameterizing your queries. String concatenation is the worst.

Comment: SIZENO,SIZE,COVERAGE,WEIGHT all numerics? remove the single quotes you have added or at least for the columns that are numeric.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your database columns are for numeric data and the values you're inserting are quoted. Removing the single quotes will fix that.

You should also parameterize your query, e.g.:

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ACCOUNT.oo.Open();
    string QRY = "insert into size(SIZENO,SIZE,COVERAGE,WEIGHT) values(?,?,?,?)";
    using(OleDbCommand ODB = new OleDbCommand(QRY, ACCOUNT.oo))
    {
        // change the OleDbType based on your actual data types
        ODB.Parameters.Add("SIZENO", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(size_id.Text);
        ODB.Parameters.Add("SIZE", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(txt_size.Text);
        ODB.Parameters.Add("COVERAGE", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(txt_coverage.Text);
        ODB.Parameters.Add("WEIGHT", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(txt_weight.Text);
        ODB.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted Sucessfully..");
    ACCOUNT.oo.Close();
}
```

Comment: `OleDbCommand` doesn´t support *named* parameters (e.g. `@size_id`) as MS SQL does. However, you can access to a parameter by its index. So the SQL fragment will be `... values(?, ?, ?, ?)`; and C# one `...ODB.Parameters.Add(size_id.Text); ...`

Comment: put `IDisposable` into `using`: `using (OleDbCommand ODB = new ...) {...}`

Comment: Your SQL when printed as a *single line* is not *readable*. Use `@"..."` string format to make your query text multilined and through that more comprehansible.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I've edited the answer based on your feedback.

Comment: This would add the parameters as string types, which is what you have stated is the original problem. The `AddWithValue` method will infer the type of the parameter from the value being added. Since you are adding `TextBox.Text`, the type of the parameter will be inferred as text. I would be inclined to use a type with the parameter, and also cast the text value to the correct type. e.g. `ODB.Parameters.Add("SIZENO", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(size_id.Text);`

Comment: See also - [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)